# VBA Macro can't find the last used cell with ActiveCell

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to copy paste some values from one (src)Workbook to my (dst)workbook by finding the last not empty cell.

In my case, the copy paste is working fine until the the src Workbook has no entry.

Outcome of my macro looks like:

```
Header - |email   |Name  |origin
1.row  - |email3  |Name2 |CH3
2.row  - |email2  |empty |ch2
```

What I expected is:

```
Header - email  |Name    |origin
1.row  - email3 |x       |CH3
2.row  - email2 |Name2   |ch2
```

My code block:

```
Workbooks.Open (Filepath & MyFile)
Range("A2").Copy
ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("AP217").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
ActiveCell.Value = "x"
End If
```

It would be great, if someone could advise.

Cheers

Comment: You should read [VBA Best Practices: Avoid using ActiveCell or ActiveSheet in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/7264/avoid-using-activecell-or-activesheet-in-excel) and also [Never assume the worksheet](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/excel-vba/1107/vba-best-practices/9218/never-assume-the-worksheet) should help you to avoid issues.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply handle the error, something like this:

```
erow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row

On Error Resume Next ' ADD THIS LINE

ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=Worksheets("AP217").Range(Cells(erow, 1), Cells(erow, 1))

On Error GoTo 0 ' ADD THIS LINE -- this cancels the "Resume next", just in case...
```